# Battleship error connecting method shoot with hit

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The issue I am having is when a user enters "A2" the program spits out it as A1. Even if someone picked "B3" it spits out A1.

There is an issue with my Shoot method connecting to my boolean hit method. I cannot seem to get the array done correctly.

Can one of you more experienced users please enlighten me on where I am going wrong.

```
public class Battleships {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] board = new int[6][6];
        int[][] ships = new int[3][2];
        int[] shoot = new int[2];
        int attempts=0,
        shotHit=0;

        initBoard(board);
        initShips(ships);

        System.out.println();

        do{
            showBoard(board);
            shoot(shoot);
            attempts++;

            if(hit(shoot,ships)){
                shotHit++;
            }                
            else

                changeboard(shoot,ships,board);


        }while(shotHit!=3);

        System.out.println("\n\n\nBattleship Java game finished! You hit 3 ships in "+attempts+" attempts");
        showBoard(board);
    }

    public static void initBoard(int[][] board){
        for(int row=0 ; row < 6 ; row++ )
            for(int column=0 ; column < 6 ; column++ )
                board[row][column]=-1;
    }

    public static void showBoard(int[][] board){
        System.out.println("\tA \tB \tC \tD \tE \tF");
        System.out.println();

        for(int row=0 ; row < 6 ; row++ ){
            System.out.print((row+1)+"");
            for(int column=0 ; column < 6; column++ ){
                if(board[row][column]==-1){
                    System.out.print("\t"+"~");
                }else if(board[row][column]==0){
                    System.out.print("\t"+"*");
                }else if(board[row][column]==1){
                    System.out.print("\t"+"X");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
    public static void initShips(int[][] ships){
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int ship=0 ; ship < 3 ; ship++){
            ships[ship][0]=random.nextInt(5);
            ships[ship][1]=random.nextInt(5);

            for(int last=0 ; last < ship ; last++){
                if ((ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0])&&(ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]))
                    do{
                        ships[ship][0]=random.nextInt(5);
                        ships[ship][1]=random.nextInt(5);
                    } while ((ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0])&&(ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void shoot(int[] shoot){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] attempt = new String[2];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
            attempt[i] = input.next();
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                if (attempt[i].length() == 2 && Character.isLetter(attempt[i].charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(attempt[i].charAt(1))) {
                    System.out.println("Good");
                    if (attempt[0].toUpperCase() == "A") {
                        shoot[0] = 1;
                        shoot[1] = Integer.valueOf(attempt[1]);
                    } else if (attempt[0].toUpperCase() == "B") {
                        shoot[0] = 2;
                        shoot[1] = Integer.valueOf(attempt[1]);
                    } else if (attempt[0].toUpperCase() == "C") {
                        shoot[0] = 3;
                        shoot[1] = Integer.valueOf(attempt[1]);
                    } else if (attempt[0].toUpperCase() == "D") {
                        shoot[0] = 4;
                        shoot[1] = Integer.valueOf(attempt[1]);
                    } else if (attempt[0].toUpperCase() == "E") {
                        shoot[0] = 5;
                        shoot[1] = Integer.valueOf(attempt[1]);
                    } else if (attempt[0].toUpperCase() == "F") {
                        shoot[0] = 6;
                        shoot[1] = Integer.valueOf(attempt[1]); 
                    }
                    return;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("invaid, please enter the proper format of letter then digit.");
                    j = 2;
                }
            }
        }
       input.close();
    }

    public static boolean hit(int[] shoot, int[][] ships){

        for(int ship=0 ; ship<ships.length ; ship++){
            if( shoot[0]==ships[ship][0] && shoot[1]==ships[ship][1]){
                System.out.printf("You hit a ship located in (%d,%d)\n",shoot[0]+1,shoot[1]+1);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public static void changeboard(int[] shoot, int[][] ships, int[][] board){
        if(hit(shoot,ships))
            board[shoot[0]][shoot[1]]=1;
        else
            board[shoot[0]][shoot[1]]=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `if (attempt[0].toUpperCase() == "A") ` should probably be `if (Character.toUpperCase(attempt[i].charAt(0)) == 'A')` and similarly for the other `if` statements.  Also change `attempt[1]` to `attempt[i].charAt(1)`.  General rule - if you find yourself comparing `String` values with `==`, you've probably done something wrong.

Comment: Also, a coding tip - always use `{` and `}` for `if` statements and `for` loops. When the next developer works on your code, you don't want them to accidentally introduce a bug because they misunderstood the scope of an `if` or `for` loop block.